# "Argument list too long" in for loop

Tags: shell, shell-script

My shell script look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.fasta
do

signalp $file > $file.txt

done
```

In the working folder I have 18.000 .fasta files. I want to run each through the signalp program. I guess its too many files in the folder, but I don't know how to adjust my code. Any help?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how your `for` loop could produce an "argument list too long"... There is no such thing, [virtual memory is the only limit here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax)...

Comment: @don_crissti - it's gotta be the quotes.

Comment: Note that "Argument list too long" is just glibc's error message for the E2BIG error code. The error code doesn't actually mean what the message says.  in the Linux kernel (for example), it can happen if an OOM occurs while copying the argument. Even if the argument list requires just one page, if that page happens to be unavailable.

Comment: Another limit in Linux's exec is a limit on individual argument length: `#define MAX_ARG_STRLEN (PAGE_SIZE * 32)`. Exceed this in any one argument, and ... `E2BIG`: you get a misleading message about the list being too long, rather than an item on the list being too fat.

Comment: Lastly, Linux's exec uses some common code for environment and argument handling. So "Argument list too long" could actually be a problem encountered in copying environment variables and not arguments.

Comment: Related: [Does "argument list too long"
 restriction apply to shell builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443380/does-argument-list-too-long-restriction-apply-to-shell-builtins)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find` :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'signalp "$1" >"$1".txt' _ {} \;
```

- `-maxdepth 1` will make `find` to search for files (`-type f`) only in the current directory
- `sh -c 'signalp "$1" >"$1".txt'` will execute the `signalp` command on all the files found and save the output to the files named after adding `.txt` to the original filenames.

Comment: Correct? #!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c 'signalp "$1" >"$1".txt' _ {} \;

Comment: Saved it as "command.sh". Then typed "sh command.sh" in terminal. What are these symbols btw? _ {} \;

Comment: @user2862862 this is a one liner..you can save it if you want though..`{}` is a placeholder used by `find` to indicate the files found..`_` is used because `sh -c` treats the arguments after the command starting from positional parameter 0..so here `_` is treated as positional parameter 0 and the file `{}` can be considered as positional parameter `.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an *`argument list too long`* error because you are not quoting your arguments. There's an expansion occurring - though it is difficult to say definitely *what* it is - on the value of `$file` which generates *more arguments*. My theory is one of your filenames contains another `*` which again expands out to match all of your matched files all over again.

You *can* do this in the shell - and you don't need to invoke a whole *new* shell via `find` to do it either.

Just do this:

```sh
for f in ./*.fasta
do  signalp "$f" >"$f.txt"
done
```

...see? The double-quotes will prevent the contents of the iterable shell variable `$f` from being interpreted any way but literally - even if `$f` does contain expandable metacharacters of kind.

Granted, though, this is *not* the best solution for groups of 18k files. It *will* work, but it would be better if you could batch it *further*.

As an example, let's assume there is some kind of *order* to the filenames themselves. Maybe they're named like...

```
aaa001.fasta
...
bbb001.fasta
```

And so on. In that case you could do something like:

```sh
for l in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v x y z
do    for  f in "./$l$l$l"*.fasta
      do   singalp "$f" >"$f.txt"
done; done
```

...and so you wouldn't need to retain the whole 18k list in memory for the duration of the loop.